# Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope

Tags: java

I'm writing a program in which pressing F4
will continuously press a certain key on the keyboard until you press another key (F2)

```
public ViewPotion() {
        int i = 0;
        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {

                if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F4) {
                    System.out.println("Iniciando AutoPotion");
                     i = 1;
                    new Thread() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                            while (i > 0) {
                                    Robot robot = new Robot();
                                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
                                }
                            } catch (AWTException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }.start();
                }

                if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F2) {
                    System.out.println("Parando AutoPotion");
                   i = 0;
                }
            }
        }); 


        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
    }

}
```

But I get the error:

> Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `i` outside of the `keyPressed` block. The problem here is that the `keyPressed` method isn't called immediately after, so `i` needs to be `final` so that you don't accidentally modify the variable concurrently between two threads.

One solution here is to make `i` a global variable (outside the method). This way, it can be accessed from multiple threads and won't go out of scope when `ViewPotion` finishes.

---

You can also clean your code up significantly by using a boolean instead

```
boolean keepPressingO = false;
public ViewPotion() {
    addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F4) {
                System.out.println("Iniciando AutoPotion");
                keepPressingO = true;

                new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            while (keepPressingO) {
                                Robot robot = new Robot();
                                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
                            }
                        } catch (AWTException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }.start();

            }

            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F2) {
                System.out.println("Parando AutoPotion");
                keepPressingO = false;
            }
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: thansk bro
but when I press f2 the program does not turn off
I believe that on account of having that the screen is open to activate
would I be able to do something to activate without having to have the screen open?

Comment: @CarlosMontana Not sure if I understand your question, are you asking whether the program window needs to be in the foreground to capture the F2? Because the program won't capture the F2 unless it's the active window

Comment: yess 
I was needing you not to need the foreground screen if you will not stay in the while forever

Comment: I think I could not do this with the java swing I do not know if there is any library for this